# Why can't eclipse properly build the .classpath?

Tags: eclipse, windows-8.1, permission-denied, buildpath

I am a LWJGL developer, and I use to develop for Mac OSX. I recently switched to a new computer, and I am finding it is very difficult to transfer my project properly.

After I installed eclipse, I imported my old project to my workspace. The project contained all the Jars I needed within it's lib folder, and I started to add them to my projects build path. After clicking 'OK' the build path window close, and a pop-up appeared with an error message; It read: "Cannot write .classpath file at D:\My Files\Programming\Eclipse Access is denied"

Now, the first thing I thought is, it must be the Windows 8.1 firewall. I completely turned off the firewall, and I got the same message. Could it possibly be because I am running my OS + All my runtime environments off a different hard drive, and it doesn't know what to do? Please help, I have a deadline of a lot of important work to do. I also apologize if my grammar is off, english is not my first language.

Note: I am the ONLY user of this computer, so I am also it's administrator.

Comment: It's not the firewall, looks like whatever user eclipse is running as does not have write permissions to the directory that the app is installed in.

Comment: I am the administrator though, I am also the only user.

Comment: Windows 8 will not let you write to certain directories.  For instance, I cannot write to C:  I am also an administrator.

Comment: Any way to override this?

Comment: Try restarting your computer. Maybe some other program is locking it and a reboot will flush it out.

Answer (score 6):

Try to uncheck the Hidden attribute for .classpath files in your projects.

Comment: I had to show the hidden files and then uncheck the hidden .classpath file.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the file is opened somewhere else. Another instance of Eclipse? Some text editor? Sometimes Windows think it IS opened somewhere else, while it is not. Then you have to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is how I fixed it.

1. close the project
2. copy .classpath to classpath.txt
3. delete .classpath
4. open the project
5. refresh
6. edit the properties for the project ( this will create a good classpath )
7. edit .classpath & put your stuff back in from classpath.txt
8. save it (you should notice there was no error this time)

Why? I think windows got confused about the file .classpath thought it was open elsewhere perhaps

Comment: This solved a very frustrating problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new project > import > file system > browser > select project > uncheck the classpath checkbox.

It's going to solve your problem.